# javascript iterating through array at certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to iterate through a playlist, but not skip to the next item until the current song is done playing or until a new song in the playlist is chosen. Currently my array is iterated, but does not wait for the current song to finish playing.

HTML:

```
<li mp3="song1.mp3"></li>
<li mp3="song2.mp3"></li>
<li mp3="song3.mp3"></li>
<li mp3="song4.mp3"></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('audio');

playlist = ['song1.mp3', 'song2.mp3', 'song3.mp3', 'song4.mp3'];

$('li').click(function() {
  for (var i = playlist.indexOf($(this).attr('mp3')); i < playlist.length; i++) {
    player.setSrc(playlist[i]);
    player.play();
    player.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      player.setSrc(playlist[i]);
      player.play();
    }, false);
  }
});
```

Comment: hint: try to get use of `indexOf` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running a plain loop, so a bunch of `.play()` calls are run right after each other. Instead, run only one `.play()`, and call the next one when the song has ended. This can be done by calling recursively. Also, use `data-mp3` attributes and `.data("mp3")`, because that's the only valid way to define custom attributes.

```
$("#playlist li").click(function() {
  var start = playlist.indexOf($(this).data("mp3"));

  (function play(i) {
    if(i < playlist.length) {  // if we're not at the end of the playlist yet
      player.setSrc(playlist[i]);
      player.play();
      player.addEventListener("ended", function(e) {
        play(i + 1);  // done, so call with next index
      }, false);
    }
  })(start);  // call it with first index now
});
```

Comment: awesome, I really appreciate it :)